# Python 3 OpenCV script that scans a giant picture to make a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, video

This is a Python script that I wrote completely by myself. Basically it scans a giant picture to make a video.

They say one picture is worth more than a thousand words. Since a video contains thousands of pictures, a video is worth more than millions of words, so I will let the video outputs do the descriptions for me (because I am not a native speaker of English and I can't even describe the process in my native language or any natural language for that matter, but I can describe it in code).

[image: vertical image]

[Vertical video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EJi1LjTYT8vkJkOrEY8VbAcLlAsAL8XX/view?usp=sharing) (Google Drive)

[image: horizontal image]

[Horizontal video Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zxJ_50B63fQ4D6-cWbGFOOoJGfSqUaQ/view?usp=sharing) (Google Drive)

For more context, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72009203/18948914).

The code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction
from pathlib import Path

def resize_guide(image_size, target_area):
    aspect_ratio = Fraction(*image_size).limit_denominator()
    horizontal = aspect_ratio.numerator
    vertical = aspect_ratio.denominator
    unit_length = (target_area/(horizontal*vertical))**.5
    return (int(horizontal*unit_length), int(vertical*unit_length))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
FRAME = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

def new_frame():
    return np.ndarray.copy(FRAME)

def center(image):
    frame = new_frame()
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    yoff = round((1080-h)/2)
    xoff = round((1920-w)/2)
    frame[yoff:yoff+h, xoff:xoff+w] = image
    return frame

def image_scanning(file, fps=60, pan_increment=64, horizontal_increment=8, vertical_increment=24):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    if width < 1920:
        frame = np.zeros([height, 1920, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
        frame[0:height, 0:width] = image
        image = frame
        width = 1920
    assert width*height >= 1920*1080
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(file+'.mp4', fourcc, fps, (1920, 1080))
    fit_height = True
    if height < 1080:
        width = width*1080/height
        image = cv2.resize(image, (width, 1080), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    aspect_ratio = width / height
    not_thin = False
    if 4/9 <= aspect_ratio <= 16/9:
        new_width = round(width*1080/height)
        fit = cv2.resize(image, (new_width, 1080), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        not_thin = True
    
    elif 16/9 < aspect_ratio <= 32/9:
        new_height = round(height*1920/width)
        fit = cv2.resize(image, (1920, new_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        fit_height = False
        not_thin = True
    
    if not_thin:
        centered = center(fit)
        for i in range(fps):
            video_writer.write(centered)
        if fit_height:
            xoff = round((1920 - new_width)/2)
            while xoff:
                if xoff - pan_increment >= 0:
                    xoff -= pan_increment
                else:
                    xoff = 0
                frame = new_frame()
                frame[0:1080, xoff:xoff+new_width] = fit
                video_writer.write(frame)
        else:
            yoff = round((1080 - new_height)/2)
            while yoff:
                if yoff - pan_increment >= 0:
                    yoff -= pan_increment
                else:
                    yoff = 0
                frame = new_frame()
                frame[yoff:yoff+new_height, 0:1920] = fit
                video_writer.write(frame)
    
    if not_thin:
        if fit_height:
            width_1, height_1 = new_width, 1080
        else:
            width_1, height_1 = 1920, new_height
        new_area = width_1 * height_1
        original_area = width * height
        area_diff = original_area - new_area
        unit_diff = area_diff / fps
        for i in range(1, fps+1):
            zoomed = cv2.resize(image, resize_guide((width_1, height_1), new_area+unit_diff*i), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            zheight, zwidth = zoomed.shape[:2]
            zheight = min(zheight, 1080)
            zwidth = min(zwidth, 1920)
            frame = new_frame()
            frame[0:zheight, 0:zwidth] = zoomed[0:zheight, 0:zwidth]
            video_writer.write(frame)
    
    if (width - 1920) % horizontal_increment:
        new_width = ((width - 1920) // horizontal_increment + 1) * horizontal_increment + 1920
        frame = np.zeros([height, new_width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
        frame[0:height, 0:width] = image
        width = new_width
        image = frame
    
    if not_thin:
        if height % 1080:
            new_height = (height // 1080 + 1) * 1080 + 8
            frame = np.zeros([new_height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
            frame[0:height, 0:width] = image
            height = new_height - 8
            image = frame
        
        y, x = 0, 0
        for y in range(0, height, 1080):
            for x in range(0, width-1920, horizontal_increment):
                frame = image[y:y+1080, x:x+1920]
                video_writer.write(frame)
            x = width - 1920
            frame = image[y:y+1080, x:x+1920]
            for i in range(round(fps/3)):
                video_writer.write(frame)
    
    else:
        if (height - 1080) % vertical_increment:
            new_height = ((height - 1080) // vertical_increment + 1) * vertical_increment + 1088
            frame = np.zeros([new_height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
            frame[0:height, 0:width] = image
            height = new_height - 8
            image = frame
        
        y, x = 0, 0
        for y in range(0, height-1080, vertical_increment):
            for x in range(0, width-1920, vertical_increment):
                frame = image[y:y+1080, x:x+1920]
                video_writer.write(frame)
            x = width - 1920
            frame = image[y:y+1080, x:x+1920]
            for i in range(round(fps/3)):
                video_writer.write(frame)
        y = height - 1080
        for x in range(0, width-1920, vertical_increment):
            frame = image[y:y+1080, x:x+1920]
            video_writer.write(frame)
            x = width - 1920
            frame = image[y:y+1080, x:x+1920]
            for i in range(round(fps/3)):
                video_writer.write(frame)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video_writer.release()
    del video_writer
```

It is in need of refactoring.

Comment: All criticism is welcome as long as it is constructive, because your criticism points out what I did wrong, so that I will not make the same mistake next time, and that's how I improve.

Comment: A warning. You say _most if not all questions posted by my previous Stack Overflow accounts were downvoted and/or closed, and the accounts eventually got blocked from asking questions._ I encourage you to read the [official guidance on sockpuppet accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/223700). If you make a new account to circumvent post restrictions on your old account, that constitutes abuse.